# Video element renders blank, no video and no errors

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I can not for the life of me figure out why the video element (photoed at the bottom) is not showing the video that I am trying to upload.

File structure is:

```
app-name/
         App.js
         src/
             components/
                    VideoForm.js
                    VideoList.js
                    VideoItem.js
             media/
                    poppies.mp4
```

```
import "./App.css";
import VideoForm from "./components/VideoForm";
import VideoList from "./components/VideoList";

function App() {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VideoForm videos={videos} setVideos={setVideos} />
      <VideoList videos={videos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

const VideoForm = ({ videos, setVideos }) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setVideos([
      ...videos,
      { name: event.target.files[0].name, type: event.target.files[0].type },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoForm;
```

```
import React from "react";
import VideoItem from "./VideoItem";

const VideoList = ({ videos }) => {
  console.log("videoList", videos);

  return (
    <div id="video-container">
      {videos &&
        videos.map((video) => (
          <VideoItem key={video.name} file={video.name} type={video.type} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

```
import React from "react";

const VideoItem = ({ file, type }) => {

  const videoPath = "../media/" + file;

  return (
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src={videoPath} type={type} />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoItem;
```

Can not for the life of me find out why the video
shows up blank with a 0:00 timestamp. The video is not corrupt.
I can watch it in vscode. I changed the permissions too.
It shows up blank for Firefox and Chrome and Brave.

[image: blank video element]

Comment: most likely invalid path for video src. For debug purpose, you can directly hardcode the src path such as `<source src={"/your-path-here"} />` to see if the video works, and then fix your path accordingly. You might want to place your video in public folder. But practically you should host it somewhere

Comment: @smunizaga Does it work with  `const videoPath = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";`?

Comment: @VC.One no it doesn't 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to place it in the `/public` directory and then to **NOT** add `public` to the filepath, because **it is assumed**. When you're running your React application, the public directory is already being served directly from the root URL, so you don't need to include the ../public/ part in your video path. For it to work, all you need to do is to provide the filename, once it is in the `/public` directory.

```
import React from "react";

const VideoItem = ({ file, type }) => {

     // Removed the videoPath variable

  return (
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src={file} type={type} /> // place in file prop as is
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoItem;
```